# Jenkins can't find docker-compose

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I created a Jenkins pipeline where I need to pull repository from Bitbucket, do a production build with Jenkins and then push the image to Docker hub. This Jenkins setup is run from docker image jenkins/jenkins:lts **on server not locally**.

In Global Tool installation I've installed NodeJS tool, with the following input for Global npm packages to install: `docker-compose@1.29.0 yarn@1.22.10`

Basically in the first stage I am running `sh "yarn"` which installs dependencies and that works as it should.
But the next stage that has `sh "yarn production:build"` throws this error:
`/var/jenkins_home/workspace/og_Online_Tools_cicd_jenkinsfile@tmp/durable-21c42918/script.sh: docker-compose: not found`

in the package-json of the project the `production:build` script is `"production:build": "u=username p=password ef=.env docker-compose up --build"`

I am running it like this in Jenkinsfile:

```
...
stage('Install dependencies') {
   steps {
      nodejs('Node 14.16') {
         sh "yarn"
      }
   }
}
stage('Run production build') {
   steps {
      nodejs('Node 14.16') {
         script {
            dockerImage = sh "yarn production:build"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
```

I've tried with:

```
...
stage('Install dependencies') {
   steps {
      nodejs('Node 14.16') {
         sh "yarn"
         sh "yarn --version"
         sh "npm install -g docker-compose"
         sh "docker-compose --version"
      }
   }
}
...
```

and the npm install goes through but it still throws an error on docker-compose.

There is also this console output from the build:

```
+ yarn production:build
yarn run v1.22.10
$ u=username p=password ef=.env docker-compose up --build
/bin/sh: 1: docker-compose: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Appreciating any insight.
Thanks

### **/////UPDATE//////**

I've entered the jenkins docker container and run curl command for docker-compose however it only created a docker-compose file in `/usr/local/bin`.
Next build attempts were throwing access denied for `/usr/local/bin`.
Now `docker-compose` installs correctly via `npm install -g` however on `docker-compose --version` I am getting:

```
+ docker-compose --version
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/og_Online_Tools_cicd_jenkinsfile@tmp/durable-a04e890d/script.sh: 1:
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/og_Online_Tools_cicd_jenkinsfile@tmp/durable-a04e890d/script.sh: docker-compose: not found
```

When I run `echo "PATH=$PATH"` I get:
`PATH=/var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/Node_14.16/bin:/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Thanks again